# How to deserialize JSON object with json.net

Tags: c#, json, serialization

```
StreamReader qryTmpltStream = new StreamReader(tmpltPath + "templates.json");
JsonTextReader qryTmpltReader = new JsonTextReader(qryTmpltStream);
JsonSerializer qryTmpltSrlzr = new JsonSerializer();
object jsonObject = qryTmpltSrlzr.Deserialize(qryTmpltReader);

var tplts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JSONRepClass>(jsonObject);
```

In above code I'm trying to read in a json file then deserialize it into a class. The problem is, this: JsonConvert.DeserializeObject wants a string, but the Deserailize method call before it returns an object.

I tried casting to string and ToString(), but no go.

Anyone see what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, just read the json file contents into a string and deserialize it using Json.Net

```
var jSonString = File.ReadAllText(tmpltPath + "templates.json");
var tplts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JSONRepClass>(jsonString);
```

Comment: Post it please, there might be some inconsistence between the json and the class.

Comment: Yes there were, I shouldn't be drinking and coding :) It's all good now. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, anytime, I feel like having a drink too. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest way to use JSON.net to turn a json string into a strongly typed class.

```
YourClass myclass = new YourClass();
JsonConvert.PopulateObject(yourstring,myclass);
```